# is GL_POLYGON_STIPPLE supported in openGL-ES 2.0?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es-2.0

http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/transparency.htm#blen0025 says scrren door transparency is achieved by enabling GL_POLYGON_STIPPLE. Is it supported in openGL-ES 2.0?

Comment: I have not searched thoroughly.It is not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking into the OpenGL ES 2.0 specification: It is indeed not supported.